# Jest Mocking Out Implementation

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have a file with this function

```
export const doSomething = (arg1, arg2) => {
  SomeClass.someFunction()
  OtherClass.otherFunction()
}
```

I've looked at how people mock stuff online, but none of them solves my case. Basically in my jest test I want to call

```
test('sendText to send text with the proper number', () => {
  doSomething()
  expect(SomeClass.someFunction).toBeCalled();
})
```

I don't exactly know how to do that. All the stuff I have looked online has mocked a function on the top level of the test function and then passed into the actual function they want to test which is very different from what I want to do.

SomeClass is a third party thing I imported for tracking and I just want to verify that it is called. Same for the OtherClass. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would do that by mocking `SomeClass`.

```
import doSomething from './../doSomething';
import SomeClass from 'module/with/SomeClass';

jest.mock('module/with/SomeClass');

test('sendText to send text with the proper number', () => {
  doSomething()
  expect(SomeClass.someFunction).toBeCalled();
})
```

Jest should be able to determine the third party module’s structure and automatically provide mocks.